# Loading multiple Handlerbars JS templates from Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, handlebars.js

I'm trying to use Ajax to load a html page which contains multiple Handlerbars templates. I've a call like:

```
$.ajax({
        url: optList.baseURL + "/HandlerBarTemplate.html",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: true,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            source = data;
            $('#hbList').html(source);           
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
```

My templates in the Html are like:

```
<script id="item-panel-template1" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

<script id="item-panel-template2" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

...
```

I've seen examples of having an individual template in a file but haven't seen any where a file contains multiple templates.

Comment: This example seems like what you're asking for? http://berzniz.com/post/24743062344/handling-handlebars-js-like-a-pro

Comment: Unless these templates are being created dynamically, why not precompile them and load them upfront?

Comment: Casey that post requires each template to be in an individual file which I wantted to avoid.

Comment: I'm using .net and running on windows so was hoping to stay away from the precompilation because of the dependencies on node.js which would mean all developer machines and build machines having to be configured

Answer (score 0):

Got this working by changing the extension with the templates to .txt

```
$.ajax({
        url: optList.baseURL + "/HandlerBarTemplate.txt",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            source = data;
            $('#hbList').html(source);           
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
```

I was then able to use the templates as if they were inline in the html.